# VSCode java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: powershell, java, visual-studio-code

I'm getting the following exception when running a java file on VSCode that uses an input file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: totalInput.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The file exists in the directory and I'm able to run it no problem with Powershell or Command Prompt. Its only when i click "Run" on VSCode that i get this exception.

Please see the image below:

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

Comment: Use the full path to the file, edit your question, but this question really belongs on Stack Overflow since it's entirely a programming question.

Comment: It a software issue since the java file runs when executed in powershell but not through VSCode.

Comment: You don't have the file in the same directory as the executable (at least not the one that VSCode started).  **This a programming problem.**

Comment: It is in the same directory but thank you for your input. I'll try posting this on Stack Overflow.

[VSCode File Structure] (https://imgur.com/aC19lY5)

Comment: It's in the same folder as the source file not the executable.  Issue a breakpoint, insert code to determine the location of the file, the code is using.  This will solve your code issue.

Comment: Thanks for that! I checked the location of the file after it's setup and it point to the project root directory since it's setup as a Java Project. Providing src\... path resolved the issue.

Thanks again for you help!